# C# Adding custom richtextbox

Tags: c#

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030837/c-sharp-richtextbox-highlight-line)

and im unsure how to add the class the user gave me - I have just created a new class file then pasted in the class and i dont know how to apply that to the richtextbox?

**Heres how my richtextbox is found... I have a richtextbox for each tabpage opened in my text editor** i created a new textbox on the newtab void

```
public RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage starting = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        if (starting != null)
        {
            rtb = starting.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        rtb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        rtb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(rtbh_MouseClick);

        //rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length, 0);
        rtb.Font = new Font(rtb.Font.FontFamily, 12);


        rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length, 0);
        return rtb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class the user gave you inherits from `RichTextBox` - so when adding textboxes to your text editor, add this custom class. And for your function of finding textboxes, use the custom control. So change the above function to this:

```
public HighlightableRTB GetRichTextBox()
{
    HighlightableRTB rtb = null;
    TabPage starting = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

    if (starting != null)
    {
        rtb = starting.Controls[0] as HighlightableRTB;
    }

    if (rtb != null)
    {
        rtb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        rtb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(rtbh_MouseClick);

        //rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length, 0);
        rtb.Font = new Font(rtb.Font.FontFamily, 12);

        rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length, 0);
    }

    return rtb;
}
```

The actual adding of the custom textbox should probably look something like this:

```
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage("Test");
tabPage.Name = "Test";
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

HighlightableRTB customTextBox = new HighlightableRTB();

tabControl1.TabPages["Test"].Controls.Add(customTextBox);
```

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer. But i cant seem to get any lines highlighting? Is it a certaian line that highlights due to my class? None of my lines are highlighting yellow :(

Comment: @user3354197 did you use the custom class given by the user when adding textboxes to your tabs? This should handle the highlighting.