# Highlight the entire line in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I want to highlight the entire line, from start to end doesn't matter whether characters are present or not and line may be blank but it should highlight the complete line.

Like
[image]

Comment: You need to know if WordWrap is on or off.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166848/richTextbox-Highlight-complete-line

Comment: Above given codeproject link does not hightlight the entire line.

Comment: The *highlight* on screenshot is a simple caret position indication. And that sounds like custom control, where redraw does that.

Comment: It could be redraw. But how can we do?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. Please ref. this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030837/c-sharp-richtextbox-highlight-line

Answer (score 0):

This will highlight a full line in a `RichTextBox` if `WordWrap` is off:

```
void highLightALine(RichTextBox rtb, int line, Color hiLight)
{
    int i1 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    int i2 = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1);
    if (i2 < 0) i2 = rtb.Text.Length;

    rtb.SelectionStart = i1;
    rtb.SelectionLength = i2 - i1;
    rtb.SelectionBackColor = hiLight;
}
```

Note that if `WordWrap` is true it will still highlight the line but only as far as it is visible. Its continuation on the next line will not be changed.

Also note that only `Text` can be highlighted. **Empty space can't be highlighted** afaik. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030837/c-sharp-richtextbox-highlight-line?rq=1) is an example of trying to owner-draw an RTB subclass..

Comment: I want to highlight the entire line even the Empty spaces.