# Highlight different lines from a textbox with different colors in C#.NET

Tags: c#, textbox

I have following problem: in my C# program, I have a function that counts items and displays them in a Windows form in a textbox like x/y.

I would like to highlight the the entire line to be

- green if x = y
- orange if x != y
- and red if 0 / y

Example:

- `10/10 Items` should be highlighted in green
- `4/10 Items` should be highlighted in orange
- `0/10 Items` should be highlighted in red

Thank you for your help :)


**Working code:**

I used a richtextbox in oder to highlight certain lines:

```
            Match search1 = Regex.Match(txt_result.Lines[i], @"(?<= wurde )(.*)(?= \/ )");
            Match search2 = Regex.Match(txt_result.Lines[i], @"(?<= \/ )(.*)(?= in )");
            if (search1.Value == search2.Value && search1.Value!="")
            {
                int c0 = txt_result.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i );
                int c1 = txt_result.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i + 1);
                if (c1 < 0) c1 = txt_result.Text.Length;
                txt_result.SelectionStart = c0;
                txt_result.SelectionLength = c1 - c0;
                if (txt_result.SelectedText.Contains(search1.Value))
                        txt_result.SelectionColor = Color.Green;

            }
```

Comment: ASP.Net? Wpf? Winforms? Silverlight?

Comment: Can you please share your C# code working?

Comment: @ZoharPeled C#.Net the textbox is in a basic Form

Comment: @Saadi i dont know how to start

Comment: Wrong control, TextBox cannot display text in different colors.  Use RichTextBox instead, change the SelectionColor property (not a typo).  Do consider a ListView, allowing the user to edit this text is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205546/highlight-the-entire-line-in-a-richtextbox/37205769#37205769) for discussion. Note that empty space after the text will usually not be colored in a RTB..

Comment: @HansPassant how does it work with a rich textBox?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, not winform, refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982150/wpf-binding-set-listbox-item-text-color-based-on-property).

---

If this is Winform, use below snippet:

```
public class MyListBoxItem {
    public MyListBoxItem(Color c, string m) { 
        ItemColor = c; 
        Message = m;
    }
    public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}


listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem(Colors.Green, "10/10"));
listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListBoxItem(Colors.Red, "0/10"));

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current item and cast it to MyListBoxItem
    MyListBoxItem item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as MyListBoxItem; 
    if (item != null) 
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString( // Draw the appropriate text in the ListBox
            item.Message, // The message linked to the item
            listBox1.Font, // Take the font from the listbox
            new SolidBrush(item.ItemColor), // Set the color 
            0, // X pixel coordinate
            e.Index * listBox1.ItemHeight // 
        );
    }
    else 
    {
         // The item isn't a MyListBoxItem, do something about it
    }
}
```

Comment: I get 36 Errors in both lines Items.Add, what did i do wrong?

Comment: @ClemensSteinbauer You've got to call your list "listBox1" in the designer part...

Comment: @MaxB my list or my ListBox?

Comment: // listBox1<br>
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;<br>
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);<br>
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";<br>
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 173);<br>
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;<br><br>
thats my code in the designer

Comment: @ClemensSteinbauer Sorry, I just checked it, the problem is the fact that you can't have these two lines (listBox1.Items.Add...) outside of the method. I believe David just pet them there as test. Take them somewhere else, like Main function or whatever.

Comment: @MaxB when I put it in the constructor I get the error: Colors does not exist, when i change it to color, I can execute it, but i never come to davids function...

Comment: @ClemensSteinbauer You've go to connect between the function to the control. Regularly you would click on control, then F4 to see its properties, there you find an event and write the function name you for that event... Or just put this line "this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);" to where you took the previous lines from.

Comment: @MaxB "go to connect between the function to the control" what do you mean by that?

Comment: got to*. You have the function "listBox1_DrawItem", but your ListBox control doesn't know about its existence. The fact that the function has the ListBox's name in its name is just a coincidence. You have to tell the ListBox that when "DrawItem" event happens, to go to that function