# Change the backcolor of current line of caret position

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

How do I change the backcolor of the line that has the caret in a Richtextbox?
The caret is gotten either via mouse clicks of the up/down arrow keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# RichTextBox Highlight Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030837/c-sharp-richtextbox-highlight-line)

Comment: It does partially. (1) the problem of having to determine the height of the line because fonts and font size may vary (2) the line I want backcolor for is the beginning of the line to the end of line where there is `vbCr` character

Comment: Sounds like progress!  Can you build a simple example demonstrating the issue? Maybe somebody will be able to fix your code.

Comment: I have eventually modified the code and it's perfectly working for me. Thanks